# Return parameter in controller instead a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller where I have a method, but I only use method in another controllers, so I don´t need to return a 
View, but I don´t know what I can return instead a return View();

Code:

```
public ActionResult language()
   {

        if (Session["UserLanguage"].ToString() == "english")
            Session["UserLanguage"] = "spanish";
        else
            Session["UserLanguage"] = "english";

        Response.Redirect("/" + Session["UserLanguage"] + "/index");



        return View();
    }
```

In conclusion, I don´t have a View so VS marked it as red

Can anyone explain me the basics of it? and what can I return instead View? Regards

NOTE: App runs 100% correctly, but I have this dude

Comment: I use it in views like `<a href="/@Session["UserLanguage"]/about" class="tg1">About Us</a></li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.Net MVC works with convention over configuration. So the convention is, When you have a statement like `return View()` from some action method, the framework will look for a view with same name as the action method name in the `~/Views/YourControllerName` directory or the `~/Views/Shared` directory. Visual studio is giving you a warning saying that there is no such view exist in this project in these locations.

Your code is working because the `return View()` will not be executed as the line above that does a redirect to the url you are passing. Simply remove the `return View()` statement.

Since your method has a return type  (`ActionResult`), you need to return something. You may use the `Redirect` method and return the result of that.

```
public ActionResult language()
{

    if (Session["UserLanguage"].ToString() == "english")
        Session["UserLanguage"] = "spanish";
    else
        Session["UserLanguage"] = "english";

    return Redirect("/" + Session["UserLanguage"] + "/index");
}
```

Since you are redirecting to an action method inside your app, you might consider the `RedirectToAction` method which will get rid of your string concatenation to generate the new url and build the correct url for you.

```
public ActionResult language()
{

    if (Session["UserLanguage"].ToString() == "english")
        Session["UserLanguage"] = "spanish";
    else
        Session["UserLanguage"] = "english";

    return RedirectToAction("Index", Session["UserLanguage"] as string);

}
```

Also **make sure you do a null check** before calling `ToString()` method on the Session item.

```
if (Session["UserLanguage"]!=null && Session["UserLanguage"].ToString() == "english")
{      
  //your code
}
else
{

}
```